# How to use jquery-Tokeninput and Acts-as-taggable-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, acts-as-taggable-on

This is how you use autocomplete with [jQuery Tokeninput](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) and [ActsAsTaggableOn](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on).

In my situation i am using a nested form but it shouldnt matter. Everything below is code that works.

### Code

Product Model:

```
attr_accessible :tag_list # i am using the regular :tag_list
acts_as_taggable_on :tags # Tagging products
```

Products Controller:

```
  #1. Define the tags path
  #2. Searches ActsAsTaggable::Tag Model look for :name in the created table.
  #3. it finds the tags.json path and whats on my form.
  #4. it is detecting the attribute which is :name for your tags.

def tags 
  @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.where("tags.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%") 
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @tags.map{|t| {:id => t.name, :name => t.name }}}
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
# It has to find the tags.json or in my case /products/tags.json
get "products/tags" => "products#tags", :as => :tags
```

Application.js:

```
$(function() {
  $("#product_tags").tokenInput("/products/tags.json", {
    prePopulate:       $("#product_tags").data("pre"),
    preventDuplicates: true,
    noResultsText:     "No results, needs to be created.",
    animateDropdown:   false
  });
});
```

Form:

```
<%= p.text_field :tag_list,
                 :id => "product_tags",
                 "data-pre" => @product.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
```

---

### Issue 1(SOLVED)

---

Must have the line:

```
format.json { render :json => @tags.collect{|t| {:id => t.name, :name => t.name }}}
```

Note - You can use `@tags.map` here as well and you dont have to change the form either.

Below are the 2 issues on why you needed to do this:

I have the following `Tag`: `{"id":1,"name":"Food"}`. When I save a `Product`, tagged `"Food"`, it should save as `ID: 1` when it searches and finds the name `"Food"`. Currently, it saves a new `Tag` with a new ID that references the `"Food"` ID, i.e. `{"id":19,"name":"1"}`. Instead, it should be finding the ID, showing the name, and doing a `find_or_create_by` so it doesn't create a new `Tag`.

---

### Issue 2(SOLVED)

---

When I go to `products/show` to see the tags by doing `<%= @product.tag_list %>`. The name appears as "**Tags: 1**", when it really should be "**Tags: Food**".

How can I fix these issues?

Comment: can you add relevant section from output of `rake routes`. Seems like there are some problems you are facing because of routes.

Comment: The only relevant section that i can think of about my routes is    new_product GET    /products/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"products"},i edited my answer and included all of my product routes.

Comment: can you post your controller method which accepts data from tag form?

Comment: I don't have a tag form though? Do you mean my ProductsController new and create methods, if so i will post those to. The tag method is already up.

Comment: Problem is taken-input submits id list back to the server and not names, and looks like act-as-taggable works with names directly. Take a look at edited `tags` action in answer.

Comment: This has helped me so much. I've gotten this to work with tags, but how can I get this to work with tags on other models? I am struggling to get this to work with tags that have other contexts. I posted my question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18272186/how-to-use-jquery-tokeninput-in-rails

Comment: In the form I also had to change `@product.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json` to `@product.tags.map{|t| {:id => t.name, :name => t.name }}.to_json` to prevent the existing tags to be sent by id rather than by name when updating a record

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should define a route in your `routes.rb` which should handle `products/tags` path. You can define it like:

```
get "products/tags" => "products#tags", :as => :tags
```

Thus should give you a `tags_path` helper which should evaluate to `/products/tags`. This should get rid of the errors you mentioned in the question. Be sure to add this route before defining `resources :product` in your `routes.rb`

Now onto [acts-as-taggable-on](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), I haven't used this gem, but you should look at method `all_tag_counts` [documentation](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/lib/acts_as_taggable_on/acts_as_taggable_on/collection.rb). Your `ProductsController#tags` method will need some changes on the following lines. I am not sure if its exactly what would be required, as I use Mongoid and can't test it out.

```
def tags
  @tags = Product.all_tag_counts.(:conditions => ["#{ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.table_name}.name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:q]}%"])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.json { render :json => @tags.collect{|t| {:id => t.name, :name => t.name } }
  end  
end
```

Comment: Take a look at my 2.Note, the link https://gist.github.com/988968,  3rd gist box. What exactly do i route to? <%= example_get_all_tags_path %> has to route to my def tags but i don't know how to and what i call the path.

Comment: Take a look at https://gist.github.com/1090097, After defining routes as shown there(4th file) you should be able to replace `example_get_all_tags_path` with `products_tags_path`

Comment: Thank you, to get this working is almost complete but theirs still 2 issues i am having. Check out my question now, i edited the whole thing.

Comment: OK, you got it working, I appreciate all of the help, i would have been at this for days. I learned a lot here because i am a rookie at Ruby and Rails, Thank you.

Comment: not sure if i was supposed to hijack this thread, so didn't. I'm having difficulty implementing this solution as well and could use some help! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8214155/using-jquery-tokeninput-and-acts-as-taggable-on

Answer (score 4):

There is a bug in Application.js code. There is an extra ) after "/products/tags.json". Remove the extra ). The code should be:

```
$("#product_tags").tokenInput("/products/tags.json", {
    prePopulate:       $("#product_tags").data("pre"),
    preventDuplicates: true,
    noResultsText:     "No results, needs to be created.",
    animateDropdown:   false
});
```

Answer (score 4):

little add-on:

If you want to create the tags on the fly, you could do this in your controller:

```
 def tags
    query = params[:q]
    if query[-1,1] == " "
      query = query.gsub(" ", "")
      Tag.find_or_create_by_name(query)
    end

    #Do the search in memory for better performance

    @tags = ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.all
    @tags = @tags.select { |v| v.name =~ /#{query}/i }
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json{ render :json => @tags.map(&:attributes) }
    end
  end
```

This will create the tag, whenever the space bar is hit.

You could then add this search setting in the jquery script:

```
noResultsText: 'No result, hit space to create a new tag',
```

It's a little dirty but it works for me.

Comment: I like the noResultsText too. Thanks for the input.

Comment: A little late, but instead of Tag.find... it should be ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag.find_or_create..., anyways, it worked for me, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the entirety of your error, but you are not hitting the proper URL with the tokenInput plugin.

This

```
$("#product_tag_list").tokenInput("/products/tags.json"), {
```

should be

```
$("#product_tag_list").tokenInput("/products.json"), {
```

As I said, I don't know if this is the only problem you are having, but if you change this, does it work?

EDIT:

I have never used `ActsAsTaggableOn`. Does it create a `Tag` model for you to use?

From the looks of it on [github](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on), if you wanted to query *all* tags, you might have to use its namespace as opposed to just `Tag`, meaning `ActsAsTaggableOn::Tag`. For example, you can see how they access `Tag`s directly in some of [the specs](https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on/blob/master/spec/acts_as_taggable_on/tag_spec.rb).

Comment: Yeah that's the problem I'm having. I'm certain if can get this page to work then i have the Tokeninput mapping to the correct place. I believe what you typed here would work but i think my controller code is wrong so its not working.

Comment: Can you post the output of `products.json`?

Comment: Edited my answer a little further based on the information you provided.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with editing the tags if for example the model failed to validate,

I changed

```
<%= p.text_field :tag_list,
             :id => "product_tags",
             "data-pre" => @product.tags.map(&:attributes).to_json %>
```

to

```
<%= p.text_field :tag_list, 
             :id => "product_tags", 
             "data-pre" => @product.tag_list.map {|tag| {:id => tag, :name => tag } }.to_json %>
```

If the form failed to validate on first submission, it was creating tags as the ID's of the tags it had created on subsequent submissions.

Answer (score 1):

Two notes: if you're getting the tags changed by numbers on the POST request, use:

```
tokenValue:        "name"
```

And if you're trying to add non-existent tags, use (undocumented):

```
allowFreeTagging:  true
```