# jquery tokeninput javascript in rails3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, jquery-tokeninput

i have a rails project that has a simple mapped relation like below:

model categories

```
has_many :stories
```

model Story

```
belongs_to category
```

in my stories controller i have

```
def new
@story = Story.new
@categories = Category.all
end
```

then in my new.html.erb i have

```
<%= form_for @story do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field, :title %>
<%= collection_select(:story, :category_id, @categories, :id, :name)%>
<% end %>
```

i want to replace the `<%= collection_select %>`(select box) with `<%= f.text_field%>`(text field) and populate the data using jquery toxeninput javascript plugin and i dont know how to go about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recently added jquery tokeninput to one of my projects and would try to give a rough step-by-step procedure to get it done:

1. Get the token input javascript and css and add it to html
2. Define a method `search_category` in your controller like following:

   ```
   def search_category
     # find the matching categories, Category.search method should implement all the logic needed
     categories = params[:q].blank? ? [] : Category.search(params[:q])

     render :json => categories.collect {|c| {:id => c.id, :name => c.name} }
   end
   ```
3. init the jquery tokeninput like following:

   ```
   $("input#whatever").tokenInput("<%= search_category_path %>", {
     prePopulate: [{ 
                    id: "<%= @story.category.id %>", 
                    name: "<%= @story.category.name %>"
                  }],
     tokenLimit: 1 // limits only one selectable category
   });
   ```

Hope it helps!

Comment: How does your form look for the TokenInput part?

Comment: form would be a normal `form_for @story` with category field defined as `f.text_field :category_id, :id => 'whatever'`

Comment: OK, Thank you. Perhaps you can answer my bounty since its pretty similar to what you've done. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674127/how-to-use-jquery-tokeninput-and-acts-as-taggable-on-together

Comment: @Rubish I have a question about tokeninput thats probably very simple for you, mind taking a quick look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819481/using-jquery-tokeninput-without-default-name