# Using acts-as-taggable-on with rails3-jquery-autocomplete?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, autocomplete, tags

I have a model called Resource that has tags from acts-as-taggable-on. I'd like to use jquery-autocomplete to make this almost exactly like stackoverflow has for tags (new ones can be created, but it suggests similar ones first with a count). Everything I've seen for this seemed like a really bad hack and didn't work well. Either they didn't work, or worked inconsistently.

What's the best way of achieving stackoverflow-like tagging in Rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

I think this episode of Railscast is just for you http://railscasts.com/episodes/258-token-fields-revised and this one too http://railscasts.com/episodes/382-tagging

I'm in the same path to make this work. There are many good tutorials on stackoverflow like: [How to use jquery-Tokeninput and Acts-as-taggable-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674127/how-to-use-jquery-tokeninput-and-acts-as-taggable-on) that can get us on the right path.